# Firebase Cloud Function - Container worker exceeded memory limit of 256 MiB with 258 MiB used after servicing 29 requests - GenerateThumbnail

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I am developing an android app with firebase as a backend. Still in prototyping phase, single user, no heavy traffic at all. I have deployed (so far) 10 Cloud Function. So far no tweaking regarding memory (256MB) or other settings. One of them is
[generateThumbnail from samples](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/main/generate-thumbnail) (slightly modified). As I am testing my app, new Images are uploaded to bucket, and thumbnails were created in same folder . . Basically, function worked as expected. However, yesterday, I got last log statement before error:

```
Container worker exceeded memory limit of 256 MiB with 258 MiB used after servicing 29 requests total. Consider setting a larger instance class and
```

and then actual error:

```
Function invocation was interrupted. Error: function terminated. Recommended action: inspect logs for termination reason. Additional troubleshooting documentation can be found at https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting#logging
```

Again, I am currently single user, and function was triggered probably around 50 times so far. Obviously something is not working as expected.

this is the function:

```
exports.generateThumbnail = functions.storage.object().onFinalize(async (object) => {
// File and directory paths.
const filePath = object.name;
const contentType = object.contentType; // This is the image MIME type
const fileDir = path.dirname(filePath);
const fileName = path.basename(filePath);
const thumbFilePath = path.normalize(path.join(fileDir, `${THUMB_PREFIX}${fileName}`));
const tempLocalFile = path.join(os.tmpdir(), filePath);
const tempLocalDir = path.dirname(tempLocalFile);
const tempLocalThumbFile = path.join(os.tmpdir(), thumbFilePath);



//foldername in docId from pozes-test collection
const folderName = path.basename(fileDir)
const docIdFromFolderName = path.basename(fileDir)

// Exit if this is triggered on a file that is not an image.
if (!contentType.startsWith('image/')) {
    return functions.logger.log('This is not an image.');
}

// Exit if the image is already a thumbnail.
if (fileName.startsWith(THUMB_PREFIX)) {
    return functions.logger.log('Already a Thumbnail.');
}

// Cloud Storage files.
const bucket = admin.storage().bucket(object.bucket);
const file = bucket.file(filePath);
const thumbFile = bucket.file(thumbFilePath);
const metadata = {
contentType: contentType,
// To enable Client-side caching you can set the Cache-Control headers here. Uncomment below.
'Cache-Control': 'public,max-age=3600',
};

// Create the temp directory where the storage file will be downloaded.
await mkdirp(tempLocalDir)
// Download file from bucket.
await file.download({destination: tempLocalFile});
functions.logger.log('The file has been downloaded to', tempLocalFile);
// Generate a thumbnail using ImageMagick.
await spawn('convert', [tempLocalFile, '-thumbnail', `${THUMB_MAX_WIDTH}x${THUMB_MAX_HEIGHT}>`, tempLocalThumbFile], {capture: ['stdout', 'stderr']});
functions.logger.log('Thumbnail created at', tempLocalThumbFile);
// Uploading the Thumbnail.
await bucket.upload(tempLocalThumbFile, {destination: thumbFilePath, metadata: metadata});
functions.logger.log('Thumbnail uploaded to Storage at', thumbFilePath);

// Once the image has been uploaded delete the local files to free up disk space.
fs.unlinkSync(tempLocalFile);
fs.unlinkSync(tempLocalThumbFile);
// Get the Signed URLs for the thumbnail and original image.

const results = await Promise.all([
thumbFile.getSignedUrl({
  action: 'read',
  expires: '03-01-2500',
}),
file.getSignedUrl({
  action: 'read',
  expires: '03-01-2500',
}),
]);

functions.logger.log('Got Signed URLs.');



const thumbResult = results[0];
const originalResult = results[1];
const thumbFileUrl = thumbResult[0];
const fileUrl = originalResult[0];
// Add the URLs to the Database




if (fileName == "image_0") {
    await admin.firestore().collection('testCollection').doc(docIdFromFolderName).update({thumbnail: thumbFileUrl});
    
    return functions.logger.log('Thumbnail URLs saved to database.');
} else {
    return ("fileName: " + fileName + " , nothing written to firestore")
}
```

This is from my package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
"firebase-admin": "^10.0.2",
"firebase-functions": "^3.22.0",
"googleapis": "^105.0.0",
"child-process-promise": "^2.2.1",
"mkdirp": "^1.0.3"
```

Can someone please explain what could be the reason this is happening. Why is this function exceeding memory of 256MB with so little traffic? ? Is this a working memory? Could it be that files are not getting deleted from tmp folder?

Comment: When you load an image file to memory it will take more (memory) space. It is not about the image size. Maybe [this video](https://www.facebook.com/watch/?v=2152615274755461) can help you understand better what happens when we load in image into memory

Comment: **Could it be that files are not getting deleted from tmp folder?** Are you deleting files from the tmp folder? If not, delete a file once processing is complete. Functions does not delete files for you.

Comment: @JohnHanley - i understands that commands fs.unlinkSync(tempLocalFile) and fs.unlinkSync(tempLocalThumbFile) should be deleting files. Question is, does this happen properly in cloud environment? Or does anyone has any ideas what is causing memory usage to be so high?

Comment: @GregorSotošek Have you checked whether your function is getting cleaned up after function is finished and You can use the `functions.logger.log` statements in your code to log information about the function's execution to get more info about the error and where it happened. Also you can use [Firebase Resize Images extension](https://extensions.dev/extensions/firebase/storage-resize-images) to generate thumbnails for the same without any code, Although you will be charged for typically around $0.01/month.

Comment: @RohitKharche - thank you for response. What do you mean by "cleaned up after it's finished"? Normally logs show: Function execution took "xxxx"ms, finished with status: 'ok'. However in that special case I got the error mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I have recreated the setup from your given code and data but I am not getting any kind of error like you are experiencing. I have also tried with a Image having large size more than 20MB but my memory consumption for the function is still hovering around 60MB/call.

And more specifically I have also tried to hammer the function with providing more than 40 times but still no error pops up for me.

I think it is best to create a github issue about this issue under the same github link you have provided [generateThumbnail from samples](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/main/generate-thumbnail), so the actual engineers behind the product will support you OR you can also try to contact [firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/contact)

Comment: Thank you, @Rohit. I appreciate this. Will try to contact support or create an issue.